# Client side validation is firing but does not show the message

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For an Email field I have this generated HTML

```
<input name="PasswordLoserEmail" class="input-validation-error form-control" id="PasswordLoserEmail" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="PasswordLoserEmail-error" type="email" value="" data-val-required="The email address is required" data-val="true" data-val-email="Invalid Email Address">
```

From this Razor code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordLoserEmail, new { @class = "form-control", type = "email" })
```

And the annotations I have added are these:

```
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
public string PasswordLoserEmail { get; set; }
```

And I have this in bottom of my `HTML` page too:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and just added this thing to my `CSS` too:

```
.input-validation-error {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}
```

But when I enter an invalid email address, although it prevents the form from getting submitted, but it does NOT show the error message to the user.
**Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a ValidationMessageFor to show the error message:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PasswordLoserEmail)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, now it is kinda working but TWO issues: As soon as page loads, it says email is required ! also it thinks an input like "abc@" is VALID !

Comment: Try [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] and [EmailAddress], both instead of the current EmailAddress attribute in your data annotations.